# precision-recall auc from cross_val_score in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, cross-validation, metrics

cross_val_score in python enables one to generate a variety of convenient model performance metrics. This is what I use to get ROC-AUC and Recall for a binary classification model.

```
  import sklearn

  from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
  from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
  from sklearn import metrics

  log = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')

  auc = cross_val_score(log, X, y, scoring='roc_auc')
  print ("ROC-AUC (Mean->): " + str(round(100*auc.mean(), 2)) + "%" + " (Standard Deviation->): " + str(round(100*auc.std(), 2)) + "%")
    
  recall = cross_val_score(log, X, y, scoring='recall')
  print ("RECALL (Mean->): " + str(round(100*recall.mean(), 2)) + "%"+ " (Standard Deviation->): " + str(round(100*recall.std(), 2)) + "%")
```

For the same binary classification model, how can one incorporate a metric for calculating precision-recall AUC within cross_val_score?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the function: `precision_recall_curve()`,
it compute precision-recall pairs for different probability thresholds.

Try the following approach:

```
FOLDS = 6
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=FOLDS, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(k_fold.split(X)):
        Xtrain, Xtest = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        ytrain, ytest = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        logistic_model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
        pred_proba = logistic_model.predict_proba(Xtest)
        precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(ytest, pred_proba[:, 1])
        ...
```